# Reset TextView values onPause()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created a login app represented by 2 EditText (username,password) and a button.
When I click login it checks of course the information and if it's wrong it prints a dialog with a try again button.
When I go back to the login activity the old username and password text are still there and I want to reset it.
I tried to do that on the onPause() method since when the error dialog pops up the onPause() method is generated but I failed.

Any Idea?
Thanks.

edit: after your advices I decided to re-arrannge my code and declare the EditText as they should be.
The result is still the same =\

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    private EditText username,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    this.password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    this.username.setText("");
    this.password.setText("");

    super.onPause();
}
public void showMsg(View view)
{
    String user = this.username.getText().toString();
    String pass = this.password.getText().toString();

    if(user.equals("a") && pass.equals("a"))
    {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        i1.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, user);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
    else
    {   
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error!");
        builder.setMessage(R.string.failure);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Try again", null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In `onPause()` just take both of your EditText's and `setText("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to do that on the onPause() method since when the error dialog pops up the onPause() method is generated but I failed.

I have no idea what that means, but you should be able to do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    editText.setText("");
    super.onPause();
}
```

If this doesn't help guide you, you need to post what you have tried and the LogCat errors. Otherwise we won't be able to help...

---

**Addition**
You don't actually leave the Activity when the username and password combination is wrong, so `onPause()` is never called. Try this:

```
public void showMsg(View view)
{
    String user = this.username.getText().toString();
    String pass = this.password.getText().toString();
    this.username.setText("");
    this.password.setText("");
```

Or if you only want to clear the username and password in the else-block (where you create the AlertDialog).

Comment: Here is what I tried: 'code'  protected void onPause()
    {
     super.onPause();
     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).setText("");
     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).setText("");
    }

Comment: Thank you for adding it to the code to your question. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an empty EditText once you click button:

```
editText.setText("");
```

or try to set a hint attribute in the xml:

```
android:hint="Enter Name"
```

Comment: I tried:  protected void onPause()
    {
     super.onPause();
     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).setText("");
     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).setText("");
    }

Comment: do the same but inside onClickListener for your login button. You don't need to make it in onPause()

Comment: I will try that and post the result but I don't understand why It's not working?one of the reason I'm doing this is to practice with the activity life cycle (pause,stop,resume etc..)